# Call onclick and onchange programmatically don't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on writing a script to automate filling a form. Sample of the part I want to fill is here:

```
<tbody><tr>
<td class="UMenuTimeSheetFirstCell">
   <div class="UMenuTimeSheetElement UMenuTimeSheetElementEditable" onclick="_UMenuTimeSheetEditClick(this);">
      <div class="UMenuTimeSheetElementDisplayValue" title="Nessuna descrizione">0.00</div>
      <input type="text" class="UMenuTimeSheetElementEditValue UMenuTimeSheetElementEditValueM" taskid="1769" refdate="1/7/2013" onchange="_UMenuTimeSheetEditChange(this);" oldvalue="0" value="0"><input type="text" class="UMenuTimeSheetElementEditValue UMenuTimeSheetElementEditValueH" taskid="1769" refdate="1/7/2013" onchange="_UMenuTimeSheetEditChange(this);" oldvalue="0" value="0"><input type="text" class="UMenuTimeSheetElementEditValueShow" onfocus="_UMenuTimeSheetCheckFocus(this);" onchange="_UMenuTimeSheetEditChangeShow(this);">
      <div class="UMenuTimeSheetElementEditDescCont" style="left: 55px;">
         <div class="UMenuTimeSheetElementEditMinutesMode">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>-</td>
                     <td class="UMenuTimeSheetElementEditMinutesModeSplitTitle">Ore</td>
                     <td class="UMenuTimeSheetElementEditMinutesModeSplit">+</td>
                     <td>-5<br>-10</td>
                     <td class="UMenuTimeSheetElementEditMinutesModeSplitTitle">Minuti</td>
                     <td>+5<br>+10</td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
         <div class="UMenuTimeSheetElementEditDesc">
            <div>Descrizione:</div>
            <textarea onchange="_UMenuTimeSheetEditChangeDesc(this);" oldvalue=""></textarea>
            <div class="UMenuTimeSheetElementEditDescClose" onclick="_UMenuCancelPropagationOnClick(arguments[0], this); $(this).parents('.UMenuTimeSheetElementEditable').removeClass('UMenuTimeSheetElementEditMode');"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</td>
<!-- more td tags -->
</tr></tbody>
```

I tried to do this to edit it
`element=cell.getElementsByClassName("UMenuTimeSheetElementDisplayValue")[0]; //get the class where to place the value
        e`

```
element.innerText=timeWorkedToday;
_UMenuTimeSheetEditClick(element); //onclick
element.parentNode.onclick();
```

This didn't work. I also noticed that there are some changes that happens when I click on the textarea. When I press enter, some calculations are done in static labels in the page and the changes done in the element are reverted.

What is the right code to do to give the same results are if the user is inputting it?

UPDATE: jquery is acceptable to solve this problem.

Comment: why is this question tagged with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to place value `timeWorkedToday` into a `div` with class `UMenuTimeSheetElementDisplayValue`.

With jQuery use this sample code:

```
$(".UMenuTimeSheetElementDisplayValue").html(timeWorkedToday);
$(".UMenuTimeSheetElementDisplayValue").click();
```

I am assuming you can use jQuery as you tagged the question with jQuery

Comment: I might assume jQuery too, because of the tags, but since there is not a single indication of jQuery in the question, I doubt it.

Comment: This partially works. It changes the value of the innerText of all nodes with UMenuTimeSheetElementDisplayValue class. What if I have a var linking to a node of the stated class and I want to give it a certain value unique to other nodes. Could you tell me how?

Comment: @M-T-A Can you elaborate what do you mean with an example? if you want to retrieve perticular element (say at index 0) you can use `$(".UMenuTimeSheetElementDisplayValue").get(0).html(timeWorkedToday);
$(".UMenuTimeSheetElementDisplayValue").get(0).click();`

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling click not onclick

```
element.parentNode.click();
```